# How to center a label horizontally for all iOS devices in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, ios9

I can't figure out how to make the label horizontally center in a image view, The label says `"You've been here. What would you rate us`, I want the `What would you rate us` to be under the `"You've been here."` What I attempted to do accomplish this was to add 2 lines to the labels and select the label plus the 3 buttons and clicked on "Add Missing Constrains". When I run the program this is the result.

How can I fix it so the text is entered on all devices?

[image]

***Constrains***

[image]

Comment: Some constraints are missing

Comment: Please try to add all constraints from your side without missing any one. Because Add Missing Constrains will add according to his logic not exactly that you want.

Comment: Can use show screen shot of all constraints.

Comment: Add horizontal centre and top constraints to your label and then do "Update Frames". This might help.

Comment: @mehulsojitra I updated the question with the constrains

Answer (score 22, accepted):

for your label try to add constraints like:

Add top, width and height constraints as shown in below screen shot and make sure that constraints to margins is uncheck.

[image]

And set horizontal center constraints.

[image]

Comment: Do I select the label and the stack view when doing the constrains? because if I don't the buttons don't appear. Since I have to select both stack view and label does the constrain change?

Comment: Your stack view contains three images(emojis) which is shown in screen shot correct??

Comment: You say that "if I don't the buttons don't appear" which button you say?(is this after the label? in screen shot).

Comment: What I did was Select Stack view and label and added 43 as you answered and I did work like I wanted it work, but I have a lot of `Issues` on the side. for example it says "Frame for Stack View will be different at run time"

Comment: I updated the question with issues shown on the side.

Comment: Hi, sorry but Don't consider value from my screen shot as 43 is top space from super view and in your case may be is 29 as you posted in your screen shot. I capture that screen shot only for displaying you which constraints are required please ignore the value of top, width and height contains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98881/discussion-between-mehulsojitra-and-francescstudio).

Answer (score 0):

Click the label

1. Don't set any heights
2. Now set top space to the container view
3. Centre horizontal to container view
4. Now set the height (or) bottom space to the smiley

Add this all constraints you will get what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Add Vertical top spacing for the particular imageview
2. Add center horizontal at in same imageview
3. Then adjust the leading and trailing as same as drag and drop way. it just easy.

Answer (score 0):

just use this code :

```
yourLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
CGPoint centerPoint = yourLabel.center;
centerPoint.x = yourImageView.center.x;
yourLabel.center = centerPoint;
```