# Custom UITableViewCell only displays one UILabel, even though there are two on storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I am making a simple contacts application with controllers: `ContactTableViewController` and custome cell: `ContactTableViewCell`. I created a custom table view cell where the style is custom, `identifier` is `ContactTableViewCell`, and class is also `ContactTableViewCell`. 
The cell has two `UILabel` fields, which are exposed to `ContactTableViewCell.swift` class as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ContactTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var info: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        print("cell loaded with name: ", name)
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Now I want to display them in my `ContactViewController`, and the relevant part of my controller looks like this:

```
// MARK: - Table view data source    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }


    // here we communicate with parts of the app that owns the data
    override func tableView(_ tableView            : UITableView
                           , cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath
                           ) -> UITableViewCell {

        let id = "ContactTableViewCell"

        // deque a cell as an instance of ContactTableViewCell
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: id, for : indexPath)
        as? ContactTableViewCell else {

            fatalError("dequed cell is not instance of ContactTableViewCell")
        }

        cell.name.text = "hello"
        cell.info.text = "hello information"
```

However, when I run the simulation I only see two rows of "hello", even though it should be something like:

```
hello
hello information
```

repeated twice. What is the problem here?

Comment: Did you configure your custom cell to have enough room to display both labels?

Comment: Could it be that `cell.info` is hidden? Did you set layout constraints? What's the height of the cells?

Comment: @MuhammadHassan I set the `row height` to 90, but it's still showing up on the my phone as something very narrow like 35. That could definitely be the issue. It looks wide on my story board though.

Comment: Implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method and give it the height you desire.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan I'm not sure how that works, could you provide a link to documentation please?

Comment: Sure. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview

Comment: @MuhammadHassan ok that worked thank you! If you want to provide the solution as an answer then I can check resolved.

Comment: You can use UIAutomaticDimension in row height and set the estimated row height on the tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you don't have enough room to fit both labels. You can either set the row height in storyboard by:

1. Selecting your tableview
2. Go to size inspector
3. Change the `Row Height`

[image: Change row height]

OR

You can implement `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` method in your `tableView`'s delegate. i.e.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // return desired height for your cell
    return 90.0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a contraint issue. You have to define height, width, x and y positioning for both the name UILabel and the info UILabel. Font size places a dominant role for height with UILabels and width can be based on the number of characters in the UILabel x font size so you do not have to explicity express height and width constraints for a UILabel, but for a UIButton you would have to explicitly define constraints for x,y,width,height. For UILabel we only have to define x and y constraints.

What happens when you do not clearly define the constraints for your UI elements is that the rendering of your View will have unpredictable results and UI elements quite often just do not appear on the view.

It looks like, from your code, you are using XCode designer to add your UILabels so that is what you can use to add constraints. You can also add constraints programmatically as well. But I am pretty sure you are using XCode Storyboard designer.

Whether programmatically or through XCode designer you need add a constraint for the name UILabel to the top and left of the super view, you can reposition later, and then constrain x and y alignment of the info UILabel to the name UILabel, horizontally aligning to the name UILabel and +8 vertical spacing to the bottom of the name UILabel, this will place the info UILabel below and centered to the name UILabel.

See this guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

And this Stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34448801/1258525

Not the first two constraints I have circled in this picture, this defines the x and y for the Video Quality UILabel:
[image]

And then see how the next label below, Onset Threshold constraints itself to the leading edge of the Video Quality label and then the divider below the VideoQuality label:

[image]

Comment: Hey @Brian Ogden you gave an awesome answer! But I had a hand shake agreeement with Muhammad to accept his answer! But this one is very very good as well!

Answer (score 1):

My theory the 2nd label is truncated not getting sufficient width, and may be the number of lines in the second label is 1. Hence try setting number of line to 0 and check the width and auto layout constraints.